# Spring Reactive Cassandra, use custom CqlSession

Tags: cassandra, spring-webflux, spring-data-cassandra

How do we use a custom CqlSession on a Spring Webflux application combined with Spring starter reactive Cassandra please?

I am currently doing the following, which is working perfectly:

```
public class BaseCassandraConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {



    @Bean
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
        final CqlSessionFactoryBean cqlSessionFactoryBean = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setKeyspaceName(keyspace);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setLocalDatacenter(datacenter);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPort(port);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setUsername(username);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPassword(passPhrase);
        return cqlSessionFactoryBean;
    }
```

However, I would like to use a custom session, something like:

```
        CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().build();
```

How do we tell this configuration to use it?

Thank you

Comment: By default you only need one session with the latest version of spring since it will create new sessions as needed by your app. What are you trying to do that you want a different session configuration?

Comment: @KenRabe Thank you for your answer. I need this:  CqlSession.builder().withClientId(MyClientId), How should I do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

If you are looking to completely override the auto configured `CqlSession` bean, you can do so by providing your own `CqlSesson` bean ie.

```
@Bean
public CqlSession cassandraSession() {
    return CqlSession.builder().withClientId(MyClientId).build();
}
```

The downside of override the entire bean is that you will lose the ability to configure this session via application properties and you will lose the defaults spring boot ships with.

**Option 2:**

If you want to leave the default values provided by spring boot and have the ability to configure the session via application properties you can use `CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer` to provide specific custom configurations to the `CqlSession`. This can be achieved by defining a bean of that type ie:

```
@Bean
public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer myCustomiser() {
    return cqlSessionBuilder -> cqlSessionBuilder.withClientId(MyClientId);;
}
```

My personal preference is option 2 as it maintains the functionality provided by spring boot which in my opinion results in an easier to maintain application over time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Michael.
I am also leaning towards your option2, as I do want to keep the Spring configuration via application.properties.
I came up with the following code, but it seems it is not working.
May I ask how do I use this CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer please?

Comment: @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}")
    private String passPhrase;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    private String keyspace;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.datacenter}")
    private String datacenter;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
    private String contactPoints;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
    private int    port;

Comment: ```
 @Bean
    @NonNull
    public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer cqlSessionBuilderCustomizer() {
        return cqlSessionBuilder -> cqlSessionBuilder.withClientId(UUID.fromString("9509d9a6-bc0f-44a3-b8d0-900fdfce8c90"));
    }
```

Comment: ```
@Bean
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
        final CqlSessionFactoryBean cqlSessionFactoryBean = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setKeyspaceName(keyspace);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setLocalDatacenter(datacenter);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPort(port);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setUsername(username);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPassword(passPhrase);
        return cqlSessionFactoryBean;
    }
```

Comment: there is no need to create your own `CqlSessionFactoryBean`. The auto configured `CqlSessionFactoryBean` will use the properties specified under `spring.data.cassandra`.

Comment: Understood Michael. However, even after I removed my own CqlSessionFactoryBean, and just leave the CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer, it is still not working. Probably I am doing something wrong.

Comment: By not working, I still see this error, which should have gone away if Cassandra was taking the new/override CqlSession with the customer UUID

Comment: Caused by: reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes
  at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java)
  at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:279)
  at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
[...]
  at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:741)
  at java.base/java.util.UUID.randomUUID(UUID.java:150)
  at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.uuid.Uuids.random(Uuids.java:242)

Comment: ahh so the issue is that `UUID.randomUUID()` is a blocking operation as it reads from  /dev/random. As this is done once on startup and not as part of an API call, I would suggest this blocking operation won't cause any issues in your app and can probably be added to the list of ignorable blocking operations in blockhound.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis Michael, very clear. Still, would it be possible to have the technical solution to workaround this?

Comment: I don't believe you need a workaround for this. The code executed at startup for a spring boot webflux application does not run on a reactive stream. As a result, code that would be deemed as "blocking" by BlockHound isn't actually blocking a reactive stream. If you are looking for how to add an allowed blocking method to BlockHound then these docs should help: https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound/blob/master/docs/customization.md